# How to create a nuget package that can be injected with little client registration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nuget

I'm new to nuget packages.

Let's say I have a simple nuget package that contains 2 classes, 1 of which I want to expose to the public - my `WidgetService`.

```
 public class WidgetService: IWidgetService
 {
   private readonly IWidgetFactory _factory; 

   public WidgetService(IWidgetFactory factory)
   {
     _factory = factory;
   }

   public IWidget CreateWidget()
   {
      return _factory.Create();
   }
 }
```

Now I have a client app that pulled in the nuget package and uses dependency inversion like so:

```
 public class MyWidgetClass : IMyWidgetClass
 {
   private readonly IWidgetService _widgetService;

   public MyWidgetClass(IWidgetService widgetService) 
   {
      _widgetService = widgetService;
   }

   public void DoTehThing()
   {
      var widget = _widgetService.Create();

      ... // do things with the widget
   }    
 }
```

Assuming the client app was using a DI framework (but we might not know which one), at a minimum what would the client have to register with their DI framework to utilize this code, if anything?

My goal is to figure out how sophisticated nuget packages expose a few simple interfaces and the rest of the dependencies are taken care of without a client app having to worry about it.

Comment: Nuget is a package manager, basically a delivery mechanism. At the end of the day they are just regular .dll references so there is nothing special about how to register types with an IoC container.

Comment: When creating reusable libraries, like you are, you should follow the [DI Friendly libraries](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) guidelines.

Comment: Thanks @Steven this is the exact concept I was looking for. But for a DI friendly library, should a library class always have constructors that supply concrete typed dependencies to satisfy the dependency requirements of the inverted constructor that requires interfaces as parameters?